# iOS WebView - How to disable web page's built-in swipe up and down gestures (i.e. javaScript, etc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uigesturerecognizer

I faced a problem with TableView with webview inside a cell - some web pages interrupt gesture events and it makes my table unscrollable. See the gif to understand the issue:

[image]

The question is how to disable webview to handle gesture (ideally only scroll UP and Down)?

First I tried this:

```
    UIGestureRecognizer *webPan;
for (UIGestureRecognizer *pan in webView.scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
        webPan = pan;
    if ([webPan isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        webPan = nil;
    }
}
```

Did not work out for me.

Than I tried to use `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` and override:

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
            
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible");
//            gestureRecognizer = nil;
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed");
            break;
    
    }
}
```

But this only allowed me to detect the gesture. I do not understand how to let tableview to handle this gesture? Am I on the right way? Please advise!)

Comment: Can you post the link you are loading in `WKWebView`? Maybe that can help us to check if there is any way to disable execution of `JavaScript` to fix your issue? Also do share the debug view of table view cell.

Comment: There is no link. There are many different advertisers markups which contains interactive content. Actually I don't want to disable it on JS level because it may works for some content but does not for others. I'm looking for the common way to disable gesture interruption and let it handle to root view.